# xcode webview error not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

This web view failed error showing the alert popup even when it is loading the website. I believe I need to delay this method in order for it to work.What will be the best method for doing this?

```
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webViewfail didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error 
{
    if([webViewfail isEqual:webview]) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Connection Failed" message:@"Check your Internet connection before refreshing."
                                                   delegate:webview
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
```

Here is how I am loading the website

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL    URLWithString:@"http://www.blabla.com"]]];
}
```

Comment: Please show the code where you are setting the load request. Also just because it failed to load doesn't mean the internet is to blame. You should check the error object returned to see the real reason.

Comment: @moo No, you don't have to delay anything. Your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: are you calling [super viewDidLoad]; ?

Comment: Yes, I am calling super viewdidload

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely an error -999 which generally happens when something from the webpage does not load correctly or a user tries to navigate back while the page is still loading. After some research here's what I found and used to keep the NetworkAlert from poping up every time but still popping up when there is no network.

```
-(void)webView:(UIWebView *)webBlog didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error{

if ([error code] != -999) {
    NSLog(@"Could not load the dumb webPage");
    //show error alert, etc.
    [self showNoNetworkAlert];
   }else{

NSLog(@"Could not load the dumb web page...just might blame user!");
    }
}

- (void) showNoNetworkAlert{
UIAlertView *baseAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle:@"No Network"     message:@"A network connection is required.  Please verify your network settings and try again."
                          delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil
                          otherButtonTitles:@"Dismiss", nil];
[baseAlert show];
}
```

Hope this helps someone...